# In openpyxl, how can I set a range using the 'get_column_letter' function?

Tags: python, openpyxl

In my Python Code, I am trying to set a range of ('E3:H28').  However, the 'H' column letter needs to be a variable.  The following code will not run for me:

```
mo = 3

bc_col = 5 + mo

for row in ws.iter_rows('E3:get_column_letter(bc_col)28'):
    for cell in row:
        ws_blnd1[cell.coordinate] = ws[cell.coordinate].value
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to install the beta of openpyxl 2.4 which has min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row parameters for `ws.iter_rows()`:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=5, max_col=bc_col):
    for cell in row:
        # do something with cell
```

Otherwise you should use string formatting to create the range:

`cell_range = "E3:{0}28".format(get_column_letter(bc_col))`

Comment: Charlie C, your 'Otherwise' solution worked for me.  Thank you very much.  Where is the best place to get openpyxl 2.4?, Rich

Comment: `pip install -U --pre openpyxl`